# Installing Cython

Tags: python, cython, raspbian

I'm trying to install `cython` on Debian "Squeezed" and it gave this error:

```
/tmp/easy_install-QDDnM0/Cython-0.17.3/Cython/Plex/Scanners.c:7090:18: warning: â__Pyx_CyFunction_Newâ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
^Cerror: Setup script exited with interrupted
```

Im trying to install these dependenices on my Raspberry Pi running "Raspbian".

```
sudo apt-get install python2.7 python2.7-dev python-setuptools python-twisted mercurial gcc g++ zope.interface 
sudo python -m easy_install cython 
sudo python -m easy_install pil 
sudo python -m easy_install jinja2
```

Answer (score 4):

I think the only error is that you actually interrupted the install.

You received a *warning*. An warning's not an error. It's just that: a warning. Life would be better without warnings; but code *can* run with warnings.

---

But then *you* pressed <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, which interrupted the install process (`^C`).

Comment: But i press Ctrl + C after it. IT just appeared in the text. Any help?

Comment: Dude, you want help? Then provide the full traceback as requested. Otherwise: no help. Thanks.

Comment: I would just like to salute your use of `<kbd>`, which I didn't know was a thing

Comment: @user1915784 Can you please try again and make sure you're not pressing anything? I can't see no reason why a `KeyboardInterrupt` (CTRL+C) would suddenly appear out of nowhere. As the name suggests, it's usually caused by the keyboard.